# How to set the Event Color in Kendo Scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm using the ASP.NET MVC Wrappers for Kendo UI and want to implement the Scheduler.
As far as I gathered, the background color of an event is determined by the color of the first resource that the event uses. Is there a way to set the color when you are not using resources?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation here: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/scheduler/resources...

> If a resource instance has its color field set the scheduler will use this value as the background of all events assigned to that instance.

It seems that it will be the color that is assigned to the first single resource selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use resources you can use **dataBound** event http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler#events-dataBound to set styles for each event manually, depending on some conditions

```
schedulerOptions = {
    date: new Date(),
    startTime: new Date(),
    height: 600,
    ...
    dataBound: function(e) {
        $('div.k-event').removeClass('special-event');
        e.sender._data.forEach(function(eventDetails) {            
            if (eventDetails['description'] === 'special event') {
                $('div.k-event[data-uid="'+eventDetails['uid']+'"]').addClass('special-event');
            }
        });
    }
};
```