# Changing colors in Kendo Scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I've got a Kendo Scheduler and I want to set the background of the events a different color, and achieved it partially by doing this:

**Razor**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<MyProj.Models.MyModel>()
    .Name("scheduler")
    .Views(views =>
    {
        views.DayView();
        views.WeekView();
        views.MonthView(mv => mv.Selected(true));
    })
    .EventTemplateId("eventTemplate")
    ...
```

**Javascript**

```
<script id="eventTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    <div class='asset-task' style='color: black; background-color: #=Color#'>
        #= Description #
    </div>
</script>
```

This works great, applying a background color from the model to events nicely. However, this is valid only for the month and agenda view, leaving the events in day and week views with the default background color, same for every event.

I have found this:

```
.AllDayEventTemplateId("eventDayTemplate")
```

And it effectively works, but only for "all day" events, not for others. For example, if an event is from 9:00 to 10:00 it isn't colored accordingly to the template definition.

The intellisense doesn't show any `DayEventTemplate` that I assume would be used for any day event, "all day" or not.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Comment: this should work; try updating Kendo UI

Comment: @LarsHöppner, thank you for the suggestion. However, I believe I am using the latest version already: Kendo UI v2014.1.528

Comment: @chiapa: use of resources is any option **[ref: Resource](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/resources)** ? If not you can update the event's div at data-bound event. Please let me know if you wish to try the data-bound event approach, which can provide you much more control compared to resources.

Comment: @chiapa Do your events actually have a  description? otherwise the element might simply have no height

Comment: @LarsHöppner, yes, they show up but with the default color. Not having height is not the problem

Comment: well, it should definitely work with this version, even without overriding existing styles: http://dojo.telerik.com/@lhoeppner/ezuri - do you have any other styles or settings on the scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your approach and it seems to be working just as you want, please have a look at the example I created and used your logic: **[demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@D_Learning/iQuta/4)**.

The only change I have done is added a css class to override the default **".k-event" and set the background and border to none**.

> ```
> .k-event{
>     background: none;
>     border: none;
> }
> ```

Perhaps this might solve your problem.

Alternatively there are other Options like use of resources: **[ref Resources](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/resources)** ?
Another option is to update the event's div at data-bound event. This approach is explained here: [data-bound event explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629847/how-to-set-the-event-color-in-kendo-scheduler?answertab=active#tab-top)

Please do let me know if above doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: You should set the template div to be 100%, otherwise for events that span more than a couple of hours, the calendar won't show them properly.